# PHP HTML CSS Beginner USE CASE / SWITCH / IF ELSE? Need advice

Tags: php, magento

Building a website using a PHP based Ecommerce product Magento.

The problem I have is that I want to use tabbed navigation.

My idea was to use CSS to show the TAB over the relevant Navigation menu item based on the URL.

However, one URL always changes, so I wanted to somehow use an ifelse statement.

I've come up with two methods that I think could work, could any experts tell me what they would think is best and how they would implement it?

#### Method 1

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="mainnav">
<li><a href="index.php" title="Welcome page" <?php if ($page == 'index.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Welcome</a></li>
<li><a href="about_us.php" title="About us page" <?php if ($page == 'about_us.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>About us</a></li>
<li><a href="services.php" title="Services page" <?php if ($page == 'services.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Services</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.php" title="Testimonials page" <?php if ($page == 'testimonials.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="contact_us.php" title="Contact us page" <?php if ($page == 'contact_us.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Contact us</a></li>
else
  <li><a href="store.php" title="Store Page" <?php ($page == 'store.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Store</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

#### Method 2

```
$URL = store.php; 
SWITCH ($sample) { 
CASE home.php: 
<li><a href="index.php" title="Welcome page" <?php if ($page == 'index.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Welcome</a></li>
  break; 
CASE services.php: 
<li><a href="services.php" title="Services page" <?php if ($page == 'services.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Services</a></li>
  break; 
CASE aboutus.php: 
<li><a href="about_us.php" title="About us page" <?php if ($page == 'about_us.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>About us</a></li>
  break; 
DEFAULT: 
<li><a href="store.php" title="Store Page" <?php ($page == 'store.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>Store</a></li>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the final form of the menu, how about abstracting it in an array?

```
$menu = array("index" =>        "Index", 
              "about_us" =>     "About us",
              "services" =>     "Services",
              "testimonials" => "Testimonials",
              "contact_us" =>   "Contact us",
              "store" =>        "Store");

/* Render the menu */
$activeFound = false;
foreach ($menu as $url => $item)
 { 
   if ($url == $page) 
   { $class = "active"; 
     $activeFound = true; 
   }
   else $class = "";
   echo "<li><a href='$url.php' $class>".htmlentities($item)."</a></li>";
  }

 if (!$activeFound)
  /* Render your changing store URL here */ 
  echo "store URL";
```

this way, you'd have to only edit the array in the long run.

Comment: you mean `echo "<li><a href='$url.php' $class>".htmlentities($item)."</a></li>";` instead of `$active`  
apart from that +1

Comment: Unfortunately, this wont work for me as the Store URL changes, so sometimes it wont contain the word Store.

That is why I wanted to use an if else statement.

So just to clarify, I can identify the URL for Home, AboutUs and Contact Us, but the Store URL changes and doesnt always reference "store".

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Wannabe I don't fully understand that but I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thats perfect mate. I think thats just what I needed. Going to try it now!!

Comment: Just to confirm I understand this:

The Array specifies the number of navigation menu items I have,

The Render Menu is the one I'm struggling with...sorry, as I say i am a beginner.

If (!$activeFound) - Basically allows me to point everything not found in the array to the Store URL.

Comment: @wannabe exactly. `if (!$activeFound)` means, if `$page` was not in the array of entries, then do some default action (like, show the store menu).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd do it this way:

In your `head`

```
<style>
a#<?= $currentPage ?> {
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Where you'll need to get the currentPage variable somehow ($_SERVER is useful).

Then just add an id of the page name to each link.

Comment: Hey, nice idea! Will work with a flat page structure only, though. But extending to sub-levels wasn't a requirement, so +1.

Comment: Glad people liked it - this is what I always do. I normally make a variable called $internal_title, then set that as the class on the links. That way it's a little more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Pekkas answer, i'd change it to include a tertiary statement, sprintf and to use php template code for the foreach loop(looks neater):

```
$menu = array("index" => "Index", 
              "about_us" => "About us",
              "services" => "Services",
              "testimonials" => "Testimonials",
              "contact_us" => "Contact us",
              "store" => "Store");

/* Render the menu */
foreach ($menu as $url => $item):
    echo sprintf("<li><a href="%s.php" class="%s">%s</a></li>", $url, (($url==$page) ? "active" : ""), htmlentities($item));
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do it this way:

```
<?php $act[$page] = 'active'; ?>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="mainnav">
<li><a href="index.php" title="Welcome page" class="<?= $act['index.php'] ?>">Welcome</a></li>
<li><a href="about_us.php" title="About us page" class="<?= $act['about_us.php'] ?>>About us</a></li>
<!-- and so on-->
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wont work for me as the Store URL changes, so sometimes it wont contain the word Store.

That is why I wanted to use an if else statement.

So just to clarify, I can identify the URL for Home, AboutUs and Contact Us, but the Store URL changes and doesnt always reference "store".

Thanks for your response.